# I cannot connect to pymongocrypt when running on Heroku: error Failed to start mongocryptd: is it on your $PATH?

Tags: heroku, encryption, pymongo

I get this error when trying to start mongocrypt on heroku

```
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/daemon.py:140: RuntimeWarning: Failed to start mongocryptd: is it on your $PATH?
[<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27020) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27020: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]> 2023-01-16T22:18:00.486207+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Below is the full stack trace on Heroku. I am trying to run an application that uses Mongodb Field level encryption on Heroku. I have no idea how to solve this and have looked around but cannot find a build pack or anything. Any ideas?

```
2023-01-16T22:17:39.839953+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/daemon.py:140: RuntimeWarning: Failed to start mongocryptd: is it on your $PATH?
2023-01-16T22:17:39.839965+00:00 app[web.1]: Original exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mongocryptd'
2023-01-16T22:17:39.839966+00:00 app[web.1]:   _silence_resource_warning(_spawn(sys.argv[1:]))
2023-01-16T22:17:49.911328+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/daemon.py:140: RuntimeWarning: Failed to start mongocryptd: is it on your $PATH?
2023-01-16T22:17:49.911355+00:00 app[web.1]: Original exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mongocryptd'
2023-01-16T22:17:49.911356+00:00 app[web.1]:   _silence_resource_warning(_spawn(sys.argv[1:]))
2023-01-16T22:18:00.485457+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.25.54 - - [16/Jan/2023 22:18:00] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2023-01-16T22:18:00.485520+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:10.1.25.54 - - [16/Jan/2023 22:18:00] "[35m[1mPOST /login HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486181+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486182+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/encryption.py", line 196, in mark_command
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486182+00:00 app[web.1]:     res = self.mongocryptd_client[database].command(
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486182+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486183+00:00 app[web.1]:     return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486183+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 805, in command
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486185+00:00 app[web.1]:     with self.__client._socket_for_reads(read_preference, session) as (
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486202+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1296, in _socket_for_reads
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486202+00:00 app[web.1]:     server = self._select_server(read_preference, session)
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486202+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1257, in _select_server
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486203+00:00 app[web.1]:     server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486203+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 272, in select_server
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486203+00:00 app[web.1]:     server = self._select_server(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486204+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 261, in _select_server
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486204+00:00 app[web.1]:     servers = self.select_servers(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486204+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 223, in select_servers
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486205+00:00 app[web.1]:     server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(selector, server_timeout, address)
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486205+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 238, in _select_servers_loop
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486205+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486206+00:00 app[web.1]: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27020: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 10.0s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 63c5cd032fd6f21815da4267, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27020) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27020: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
2023-01-16T22:18:00.486207+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

@kevinAlbs comment below was helpful as I looked at setting bypass_auto_encryption=True and it seemed at first to get round the issue of mongocrypt. I set this in the fle_opts when creating the MongoClient, however by passing auto encryption just meant that I was not able to encrypt any of the data, even though encrypted data could be retrived?

```
    with MongoClient(os.environ.get("MONGO_URI"), auto_encryption_opts=fle_opts) as client:
```

Then the fleoptions are:

```
fle_opts = AutoEncryptionOpts(
    kms_providers , keyStore, bypass_auto_encryption=True
)
```

There are a whole host of options you can set:

```
class AutoEncryptionOpts(object):
"""Options to configure automatic client-side field level encryption."""

def __init__(
    self,
    kms_providers: Mapping[str, Any],
    key_vault_namespace: str,
    key_vault_client: Optional["MongoClient"] = None,
    schema_map: Optional[Mapping[str, Any]] = None,
    bypass_auto_encryption: bool = False,
    mongocryptd_uri: str = "mongodb://localhost:27020",
    mongocryptd_bypass_spawn: bool = False,
    mongocryptd_spawn_path: str = "mongocryptd",
    mongocryptd_spawn_args: Optional[List[str]] = None,
    kms_tls_options: Optional[Mapping[str, Any]] = None,
    crypt_shared_lib_path: Optional[str] = None,
    crypt_shared_lib_required: bool = False,
    bypass_query_analysis: bool = False,
    encrypted_fields_map: Optional[Mapping] = None,
) -> None:
```

Perhaps setting the mongocryptd_uri to a different address would solve this?

I am really poking in the dark here if anyone can help?

Comment: There are additional dependencies for [Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/encryption.html).

Comment: What do you mean? How will that solve this issue? AS far as I can see mongocryptd needs to connect to something...

Comment: mongocryptd is a local process. By default, pymongo spawns and connects to mongocryptd when a client is configured with auto_encryption_opts.
mongocryptd is used for auto encryption. If auto encryption is not needed (e.g. if only explicit encryption is used), configure bypass_auto_encryption=True. If auto encryption is needed, mongocryptd will need to be available. I am not sure if mongocryptd can be deployed to Heroku.

Comment: Why would I need auto encryptioon? Like what is the difference between that and by passing it? My server code runs on heroku but connects to mongodb. If I cannot use mongocrypt then how can I make mongodb field level encryption work? Do I need to host it myself?

Answer (score 0):

kevinAlbs comment above was helpful as I looked at setting

> bypass_auto_encryption=True

and it seemed at first to get round the issue of mongocrypt. I set this in the fle_opts when creating the MongoClient, however by passing auto encryption just meant that I was not able to encrypt any of the data, even though encrypted data could be retrived?

Looking into Auto Encryption further...

Auto encryption is the process of transparently encrypting data. An alternative is to use explicit encryption. But it requires manually encrypting each value. Explicit Encryption shows an example.

When I tried to change the mongocrypt_uri to point to atlas it did not work because mongocryptd is expected to run on the same machine as the application. It binds to localhost.

If auto encryption is required, then mongocryptd is required. The mongocryptd binary needs to be on the same machine. mongocryptd can be downloaded from the "Archive" downloads here: [MongoDB Enterprise Downloads | MongoDB.](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/enterprise/releases)

I believe if you are not going to use Automatic encryption, then you need to bypass mongocryptd (which maybe the only option on heroku as it might not support Mongocryptd) and use explicit encryption as described here:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/csfle/fundamentals/manual-encryption/#std-label-csfle-fundamentals-manual-encryption-automatic-decryption